# PHP: Find elements in deep array, then modify each parent element

Tags: php, recursion

I have a varying level of deepness for a multidimensional array. I want to find the elements where UserId isset (see example array below), then add a key/value pair (`[show] => true`) to the matched element and each parent array. There may be multiple matches that will need to modify the parents.

I have this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [parent_id] => 0
                [ownerEntityId] => 2
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 15
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [ownerEntityId] => 14
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 17
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                                                [userId] => 2
                                            )
                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 18
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                                            )
                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 19
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 11
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                            )
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 26
                [parent_id] => 1
                [ownerEntityId] =>
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 23
                                [parent_id] => 26
                                [ownerEntityId] => 24
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 41
                                [parent_id] => 26
                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                            )
            )
)
```

I want this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [parent_id] => 0
                [ownerEntityId] => 2
                [show] => true //***Added
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 15
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [ownerEntityId] => 14
                                [show] => true //***Added
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 17
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] =>
                                                [show] => true //***Added
                                                [userId] => 2
                                            )
                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 18
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                                            )
                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 19
                                                [parent_id] => 15
                                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 11
                                [parent_id] => 3
                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                            )
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 26
                [parent_id] => 1
                [ownerEntityId] =>
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 23
                                [parent_id] => 26
                                [ownerEntityId] => 24
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 41
                                [parent_id] => 26
                                [ownerEntityId] => 
                            )
            )
)
```

I have been messing with multiple recursion functions that have failed me miserably.

Comment: Would a simple `foreach` loop not suffice here?

Comment: It wouldn't be "simple" as I believe it needs a recursion function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/HoJPry

```
function hasUserId (&$el) {
    if(isset($el['children'])) {
        $ret = false;
        foreach($el['children'] as &$child) {
            if(hasUserId($child)) {
                $ret=true;
            }
        }
        if($ret) {
            $el['show']=true;
            return true;
        }
    } ;
    if (isset($el['user_id'])) {
        $el['show']=true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($top as $i => $t)
{
    foreach($t['children'] as $n => $mid)
    {
        foreach($mid['children'] as $x => $bottom)
        {
            if($bottom['id'] !== $target_id)
                continue;

            $top[$i]['show'] = true;
            $top[$i]['children'][$n]['show'] = true;
            $top[$i]['children'][$n]['children'][$x]['show'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he said varying depths of array. hence static solution won't work, recursion has to applied

Comment: Well, he's going to have to pass keys all the way down regardless so, assuming his array doesn't have crazy levels to it, he might be better served by going with efficiency of man-hours rather than efficiency of code and just nest sufficient loops to catch them (setting flags as he goes).

Comment: It's very possible that it would go very deep as this array is attached to a corproate structure that can get pretty complicated and deep levels.